# Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:

Tags: php, oop

I wrote two classes where the second extends the first one, and when I try to use it I get this error :

**Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:**

*Code logic :*

```
class foo
{
    public static function fooFunc()
    {
        return self::$fooVar;
    }
}

class bar extends foo
{
    protected static $fooVar = 'Hello World';
}

bar::fooFunc();
```

How to make it to work?

Comment: declare `$fooVar` as a public static variable in the parent class.

Comment: foo is a parent class and how is it supposed to know what's inside bar ?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `self` with `static`:

```
class foo
{
    public static function fooFunc()
    {
        return static::$fooVar;
    }
}

class bar extends foo
{
    protected static $fooVar = 'Hello World';
}

bar::fooFunc();
```

---

Futhermore adding a "default  variable" to the `foo` class is a good idea in case you forget to define the static variable in the child class:

```
class foo
{
    protected static $fooVar = 'Default Text';

    public static function fooFunc()
    {
        return static::$fooVar;
    }
}
```